# In django i created a login and register page I enter some data in it and submit but it shows page not found error codes are below

Tags: python-3.x

Here's the views.py page, which I created separately for the 'login' and 'register' pages.

[image: Views]

Here is my login & register pages:

[image: Login]

[image: Register]

However, it is displayed like so:

[image: ErrorPage]

Here is my 'urls' page:

[image: URLSpage]

[image: WebsiteUrls]

Comment: Please format your question so all images and code are in the question not in links

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in the `return redirect` part, once the user has logged in , you are again redirecting him/her to `login` page.
`return redirect('login')` is incorrect.

Take the reference from the given code base below:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        user = auth.authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
        if user is not None:
           auth.login(request,user)
           return redirect('home')
        else:
           messages.info(request,'Informations are incorrect')   
           return render(request,'books/home.html')
```

In your case `return redirect()` path is wrong, make it correct,

take help from
`https://github.com/DextroLaev/Book_Store-Django` here.

Comment: sir it still didn't work. whether page not found error will come only if we make mistake in url path or any path related issue

Comment: @Harishnitthin its clear from your error screen shot the path you are trying to reach is `/users/login/login` but your login path is actually `/users/login` so you need to check why you are putting an extra `login` at the end of the url